# Qt template DLL "function marked as dllimport"

Tags: c++, qt, templates, dll

I am having a serious issue with my DLL in Qt. When I compile my most recent additions (assertInt() and randomInt()), i get the following compile error

error: function 'T randomInteger(const T&, const T&)' definition is marked dllimport

Obviously I can force the program to compile by replacing JECLIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT with Q_DECL_EXPORT but then I would have to change it back to import when using the library. That would be a pain.

Does anyone know why these two particular subroutines are being flagged as DLLIMPORT instead of export? The rest of the library exports as it should. I have defined JECLIBRARYSHARED in my .pro file.

This is the how QtCreator generated the DLL exporting code when i created the DLL project.

JecLibary_global.h

```
#ifndef JECLIBRARY_GLOBAL_H
#define JECLIBRARY_GLOBAL_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>

#if defined(JECLIBRARY_LIBRARY)
#  define JECLIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define JECLIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT Q_DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // JECLIBRARY_GLOBAL_H
```

JecMath.h

```
#ifndef JECMATH_H
#define JECMATH_H

#include <QList>
#include <QTime>

#include <JecLibrary_global.h>
#include <JecUtils.h>

template<class T>
T JECLIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT randomInteger(const T& max, const T& min = 0)
{
    assertInteger(max);

    qsrand((uint)QTime::currentTime().msec());
    return qrand() % ((max + 1) - min) + min;
}
```

JecUtils.h

```
#include <typeinfo>

#include <QString>
#include <QRegExp>

#include <JecLibrary_global.h>

template<class T>
void JECLIBRARYSHARED_EXPORT assertInteger(const T& var)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(T) != sizeof(bool) ||
            sizeof(T) != sizeof(char) ||
            sizeof(T) != sizeof(short) ||
            sizeof(T) != sizeof(int) ||
            sizeof(T) != sizeof(long), "T is not an integer.");
}
```

The only things different about these subroutine is that they are templated. I'm also wondering if there is a dependency issue because JecMath.h includes JecUtil.h so JecLibrary_global.h gets included twice but I thought that the #Ifndef would protect against that. I'll try some experimenting and post any results i may get.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you,

Jec

Comment: I forgot to mention that I have only pasted the relevant code from these files. They are all protected by #ifndef statements; i just neglected to past it in the JecUtils.h snippit.

Comment: JECLIBRARY_LIBRARY is not #defined.

Comment: I have the following in my .pro for the dll project "DEFINES += JECLIBRARY_LIBRARY". That should define it right?

Comment: Ok I tried putting the "DEFINES += JECLIBRARY_LIBRARY" in the .pro of the program using the dll and it compiled correctly. Interesting.

Comment: @jecjackal when you added "DEFINES += JECLIBRARY_LIBRARY", it simply got define'd as empty, and therefore removed from code. Code compiles well witohut any export marking at all - I was always wondering what are those markings for anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you going to import or export `template` function? Template function has no any code to export. Caller first provides *actual definition* for template function, then code for that *actual definition* is generated.

So, you cannot export

```
template<typename T>void foo(T param);
```

When you use this function as `foo(intValue);` you provide actual definition for the template and then code for `void foo(int param)` is generated, but there is no any way to generate code until you know what is `typename T` actually.

Actually as the function is defined in header, you shouldn't mark it neither `dllexport` nor `dllimport`

Also you cannot `dllimport` a function, that has a *defenition* (not *declaration*), obviously.